# Parse: Retrieving entire column and adding it to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, parse-server

[image: Parse Server Dashboard]

I am trying to retrieve the "highscore" column. I want to display all of its values in a list view for a leaderboard activity in my android app. The activity starts but the list view is blank.

```
 public class LeaderboardsList extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> highscores;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboards_list);

highscores = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, highscores);


    final ListView leaderboardList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
    query.addAscendingOrder("highscore");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if(e == null){

                if(objects.size() > 0){

                    for(ParseObject object: objects){

                            highscores.add(String.valueOf(object.getNumber("highscore")));

                    }

                    leaderboardList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                }

            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: After you have highscores, you need to update the adapter. You can either move the line, arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, highscores);, or call arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after your highscores for loop.

Comment: I reverted to Google Play Leaderboards, but thanks